# How to delete all files that are returned by locate

Tags: command-line, pipe

At the moment his is what I do:

Step 1:

```
locate fooBar
/home/abc/fooBar
/home/abc/Music/fooBar
```

Step 2:

Manually perform a removal, by copy-pasting each line.

`rm /home/abc/fooBar`
`rm /home/abc/Music/fooBar`

How do I do this in one step? Something like

locate fooBar > rm

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want this?
`rm -i `locate fooBar``

Comment: I am not sure what the above does. I just want to remove all the files, from the paths that are returned when i run a locate command.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the other chaps have already mentioned, xargs is your friend. It's a really powerful tool and I'll try to explain it and provide a workaround for a common gotcha.

What xargs does is take a line from the input, and append it to another command, executing that other command for every line in the input. So by typing `locate foobar | xargs rm -f`, the output of the locate command will be **patched onto the end** of the `rm -f` command, and executed for each line produced by `locate foobar`.

The gotcha:

But what if there are spaces in your line(s) returned by locate? That will break the `rm -f` command because the arguments passed to rm need to be files (unless you use the -r switch), and a file-path needs to be escaped or quoted if it contains spaces.

xargs provides the -i switch, to *substitute* the input into the command that follows instead of just appending it. So I'd change the suggestion to

```
locate foobar | xargs -ixxx rm -f 'xxx'
```

which will now only break if the filenames returned by locate contained apostrophes.

I have to concur with qbi, that you should be *careful about using* **rm -f** !
Use the -p flag to xargs, or just run the locate foobar by itself before feeding it to xargs, or drop the -f from rm.

```
locate foobar | xargs -p -ixxx rm -f 'xxx'
```

Comment: To be robust against files with exotic characters (newlines, quotes, apostrophes, etc.) in their names, you can use the `-0` (`--null`) option to locate and xargs. This uses the safe ASCII NUL character to separate filenames: `locate -0 foobar | xargs -0 rm`

Comment: +1 for the reply, and selected for mentioning the gotcha ^_^

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: Worked partially

Comment: Hi I get the `permission denied` error. I guess I need to add `sudo` to this command. I tried with `sudo locate foobar | xargs rm -f`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 9):

You maybe need some more options for use with `xargs`. Test it first with `xargs -p`. If it is OK, remove the `-p` option:

```
locate foobar | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 7):

To delete all the files that are returned by locate,issue the following command in your terminal

`locate foobar | xargs rm -f`

Answer (score 0):

A less succinct alternative is to use a [loop](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_01.html) with [command substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html#CSPARENS):

```
for file in $(locate foobar); do rm "$file"; done
```

The `$(locate foobar)` bit uses the output of the `locate foobar`, then the `for` loop allows you do run something on each line of this. The quotes around `$file` should allow this to work with spaces in filenames.

Although `xargs` is more concise, the loop might be better suited if you want to expand the logic, for example, running multiple commands within the loop.

As others have suggested, either run `locate foofar` first or add the `-i` option to `rm` to avoid doing something really bad and deleting a file you didn't mean to delete